# Preparing data in TLV8

Tags: ios, bluetooth, homekit, tlv

I'm writing a HomeKit (so perhaps Bluetooth) characteristic in TLV8 format. Apple doc says

> The value is an NSData object containing a set of one or more TLV8's,
>   which are packed type-length-value items with an 8-bit type, 8-bit
>   length, and N-byte value.

According to Wikipeida a type-length value is

> **Type**
>
> A binary code, often simply alphanumeric, which indicates the kind of field that this part of the message represents;
>
> **Length**
>
> The size of the value field (typically in bytes);
>
> **Value**
>
> Variable-sized series of bytes which contains data for this part of the message.

I have no idea how to pack one. I suppose I can write raw bytes to NSData, but what do I write for pad, if I need any padding, etc. So is there an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh I figured it out.
TLV8 consist of three sections: "Tag", "Length", and "Value". I don't know what 8 means.

Both tag and length are UInt8. I believe what the tag may be depend on where the TLV8 is used. Length is the length of the value. Value is the content it self.

So when I want to send a simple 1 as a value, I use:

```
let tag = 0x02 // For example
let length = 0x01
let value = 0x01
let data = Data(bytes: [tag, length, value]) // NSData
```

Comment: Swift seems to not be able to infer the type anymore from the code above.

This seems to work though:

   `code let tag: UInt8   = 0x02
     let length: UInt8 = 0x01
    let value: UInt8  = 0x01
        
    let bytes:[UInt8] = [tag, length, value]`

Comment: The 8 in TLV8 indicates that the type and length are 8-bit